# How to use aws-cli with local dynamoDB ?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am struggling with using aws-cli with dynamoDB running on my local machine, could anyone please help.

DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:

```
Port:   8000
InMemory:   false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.CLI.html):

> Using the AWS CLI with Downloadable DynamoDB
>
> The AWS CLI can interact with DynamoDB running on your computer. To enable this, add the --endpoint-url parameter to each command:
>
> --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
>
> Here is an example, using the AWS CLI to list the tables in a local database:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Note: if you don't have any AWS credentials configured yet, the command above may fail with `You must specify region` or `Unable to locate credentials` error. For the local connection any credentials would work, so arbitrary values can be used, for example, like this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=X AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=X aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region x
```

Comment: Tried that command after following [the instructions here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html), and received, `You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".` (Am using port of 8000, fwiw.) Running `aws configure` and selecting defaults did not select a region either. Doesn't seem like you'd need one locally, but...

Comment: Same for me, maybe some defaults has been changed, although `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region local` works for me (actually with any value, like `--region x`).

Comment: I had to run `aws configure` with Key ID = *None*, Secret Key = *None*, region = *local* and format = *json* to get it running. No need to specify `--region x` afterwards.

Comment: even simpler: `printf "None\nNone\nlocal\njson\n" | aws configure`

Comment: This way to use AWS CLI worked in my localhost dynamoDB running using .jar file.

Comment: This is not complete, aws configuration is required with dummy values.

Comment: @srirachapills yes, as discussed in the comments above any credentials work, so if you have something configured already, it will work without any additional parameters. I've also updated the answer to mention the issue and a workaround.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with the region mentioned by @ruffin and got around it by setting it in an env variable like: export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1. Then I was able run dynamodb commands locally with the aws cli

Comment: "Default output format" should be table, json or text

Answer (score 9):

All is need is to run `aws configure`:

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: "fakeMyKeyId"
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
Default region name [None]: x
Default output format [None]:
```

After that.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000

{
   "TableNames": []
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Other alternative: Create the **"myprofile"** profile.

```
aws configure --profile myprofile
AWS Access Key ID [None]: "fakeMyKeyId"
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: "fakeSecretAccessKey"
Default region name [None]: x
Default output format [None]:
```

Then

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --profile myprofile
    
{
   "TableNames": []
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when using ubuntu wsl, I also restarted my computer because I had a  suspicion it might've been something going wrong with localhost but this answer at the end  of the day made it all work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=region AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=id AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=key aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

Only specifying the `endpoint-url` was not enough.